# website looks awesome when working with live server, but terrible when opening without live server

Tags: javascript, html, css

When i work with my website through live server everything looks how i wanted. But when i'm trying open index.html directly with some browser, chrome for example, my icons that i took from the Font Awesome website are scrambled, and everything that relatable with js files are not working.

this is how it looks with live server:
[image]

and this is how it looks when without live server:
[image]

I have a language translator website, and for words translation i use MyMemory API (https://mymemory.translated.net/doc/spec.php). Notice, that select tags are empty on second image. I fill them in js file, so it seems like html does not see js files at all.

i've created github with code so you could see picture more detailed https://ygorbaddz.github.io/test/

i tried to open website with github pages and even turning index.html file into index.hma, but results are the same.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878)

Comment: You are using absolute URL's,  `<script src="/js/countries.js"></script>`  Change to use relative,  `<script src="./js/countries.js"></script>`

Comment: thanks, i already changed and now everything works fine. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that every file has the following
`./fileURL`
Then it will work with both live server and normal ones.

Comment: Yes, that solves my problem. Thank you so much!